# Logstash sync database with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, celery

I'm trying to implement something like https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-keep-elasticsearch-synchronized-with-a-relational-database-using-logstash where it uses logstash `jdbc` input and `elasticsearch` output

I can make it work with simple queries.

But it's getting harder to properly prepare(serialize) data (with multiple joins and etc) for output.
(When you have data from multiple tables and need to properly format data for ES, it's harder to do it in sql query)

I'm wondering if I could program the serialization part in python rather than sql.

I could do this by running a periodic celery task. 
Would it be feasible to do this in logstash or is there any advantage of doing it in logstash actually?

(well one is logstash keeps track of `tracking_column` , but with celery I 'll have to implement that myself)

Comment: Hi i am doing the same operation with logstash.. my first question: what do you mean by celery task?

Comment: celery could run a periodic task (such as, select records that are modified after last check, and insert into ES), as logstash could do. (celery task is analogous to logstash pipeline)

Comment: I see. With logstash, I am honestly not a fan.. you need to have a rather flexible index (meaning mapping set to dynamic) and I believe it performs better when used in conjunction with filebeat

Comment: After googling, I see it is a job queue.. back to your question: from my understanding, Logstash can match the database columns with the ES fields to migrate data, but it is tricky writing queries. Its recommended to use filters (e.g. grok plugin) let me know what you end up doing!